# Intellij idea uml diagram getter/setters

Tags: java, intellij-idea, uml

So i have intellij idea ultimate.I generated uml diagram for my code. but it created getter/setter methods in my uml diagram too.

How can i delete my accessor methods in my diagram ?

instead of getter/setters i just want to write Accessor methods

Comment: you do not have diagram setting to hide some members ? (the documentation https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/class-diagram.html is unfortunately very reduced)

Comment: yes i think there should be hide option or choose whatever i want option but unfortunately i couldn't find

Comment: UML is just a plug-in for it, you cannot hope what you have in a standard UML tool

Comment: i thought hiding member is simple feature.I don't know

Comment: Yes, may be you can propose them to add. After you have to understand that a simple feature + an other simple feature + ... and you obtain a complex tool, oceans are made from simple H2O molecules :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For now, this feature is not available in IntelliJ IDEA.
Please vote on the related issue in order to prioritize the feature request: [IDEA-97872](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-97872)